# How do I make Hangfire pick jobs queued in the last hour?

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-autofac

My requirement is to process only latest jobs and ignore older jobs. How do I configure that in Hangfire?

I have tried IApplyStateFilter for setting ExpirationAttribute

```
public class ExpirationAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IApplyStateFilter
{
    private int _hours;
    public ExpirationAttribute(int hours)
    {
        _hours = hours;
    }
    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        context.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(_hours);
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        context.JobExpirationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(_hours);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (or maybe as a failsafe mechanism) is to check the creation DateTime of the job when it is started. The downside is that the Job will be queued and marked as completed.

```
public static void MyJob(PerformContext context)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(context.BackgroundJob.CreatedAt).TotalHours >= 1)
    {
        // Job is older than 1 hour
        return;
    }

    // Process job...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to this:

```
public class ExpirationAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IElectStateFilter
{
    private int _hours;

    public ExpirationAttribute(int hours)
    {
        _hours = hours;
    }
    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        var processing = context.CandidateState as ProcessingState;
        if (processing == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (DateTime.UtcNow - context.BackgroundJob.CreatedAt > TimeSpan.FromHours(_hours))
        {
            context.CandidateState = new SucceededState(new { }, 0, 0) { Reason = "Execution skipped due to expiration." };
        }
    }
}
```

It simply moves jobs past their expiration to succeeded instead of processing them. I haven't tested it at all but should be generally correct.